# How to make change language system in shopify without any apps

Tags: javascript, shopify, liquid

How to make change language system in shopify without any apps?
i have 2 locales file: ru, lv
and i need to change language by any url or something like that, how to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

Shopify stores can have dynamic URLs generated for them when they sell in multiple languages. When you add an additional locale (which you already did), Shopify automatically creates a URL path for it.

Some examples:

```
https://myshop.com -> Refers to your `locales/*.default.json`
https://myshop.com/ru -> Refers to your `locales/ru.json`
https://myshop.com/lv -> Refers to your `locales/lv.json`
```

So the solution to your problem is to simply redirect a user to another locale path (or give users the possibility to it via [language selector](https://shopify.dev/themes/internationalization/multiple-currencies-languages#the-language-selector)).

I recommend reading Shopify's [Support multiple currencies and languages](https://shopify.dev/themes/internationalization/multiple-currencies-languages) documentation.